# Boxed layout in latex

Tags: boxes

I am working on a project where the task is to design a page with a box layout in latex. Something like this:

[image: Intended layout]

I looked into [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes), but I am unsure as to how to make the boxes "respect each other's sizes", meaning that the lower boxes should span as much space is available to them to below. Similarly, boxes on the same horizontal level should be "packed together".

It will be even better if somehow the layout could be given some sort of "flexible and fluid" nature (similar to that in bootstrap). How will I be able to achieve using latex?

Comment: You want to create a single poster page or something similar OR a "normal" document with running text accross lines where the textbox is shapped dynamically? In the first case TikZ is a good way to go.

Comment: You could also have a look at the `tcolorbox` package and its libraries for `raster` and `magazine`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I want to create a single poster page.... So, then is TikZ a good option?

Comment: @Python_user: Yes, indeed, for example check out the [tikzposter](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter) package.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks a lot! `tcolorbox` suffices my needs!